# How is the micro code executed within a processor?

Tags: computer-architecture

How does the microprocessor convert the machine code to micro code?
What part of the processor is at play?

Comment: Welcome to SE Computer Science.  Have you tried to find this information on the Internet? What did you get? Why is not sufficient for your need? What difficulty do you need  to clarify. This site is a place where everyone tries to contribute by asking well thought out questions (when possible, some are hard to formulate) and well documented questions so as to help users who give their time to answer. If you searched without success, you may say so.  See, e.g., http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1911

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of a lack of research by the asker. This is answered by any computer architecture textbook.

Comment: I did try to find it on the net. But there is no disclosure upon what part of the processor does it and how.

Comment: If this question is considered off-topic, maybe it should be migrated to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ where I found a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Control Unit converts machine instructions into micro-code.

There are two types of control units; Micro-programmed & Hardwired. Both work differently.

In micro-programmed control the control unit is an interpreter for the individual machine instructions. It runs in a loop interpreting instruction after instruction, generating the required micro-instructions and control & timing signals.

In hardwired control the control unit is a state machine which takes logic signals from the instruction and generates various control signals which run the hardware.